# Where sales manager of WP-Commerce plugin?

Tags: plugins, plugin-wp-e-commerce

This is screenshot after when i installed wp-commerce plugin

[image]

This is manager screenshot on ecommerce plugin website 
http://getshopped.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/screenshot-install-06.jpg

i can't to find out sales manager like as on ecommerce website.

Comment: Hello,
I have the same problem, it seems that in the 3.8.3, there's no sales dashboard !
I'm wondering about downgrading the plugin because I've added some specific developpement.
Is there an issue to manage sales adding a plugin or something.
Thank you.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15491/where-sales-manager-of-wp-commerce-plugin/15515#15515

Comment: Whoever down-voted this question, please explain why. I currently see nothing wrong with it.

Comment: This question remains unresolved. There is no sales log tab in the 'Store' for my version of wp-commerce. I only need to know how to add it back on.

Answer (score 2):

Look under Dashboard > Store Sales

[image: store sales]

Comment: That’s a really odd place.